# NodeJS unindent repl

Tags: javascript, node.js, read-eval-print-loop

When prototyping a function in the nodejs repl I am unable to get back to the actual repl after completing the function like so:

```
> function build_color_pallete(ruleLen) {
... function get_random_color() {
..... var letters = '0123456789ABCDEF'.split('');
..... var color = '#';
..... for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
....... color += letters[Math.round(Math.random() * 15)];
....... }
..... return color;
..... }
... 
...
```

Is there a special technique / keybinding for returning to the repl so I can execute the function?

Comment: You have three opening `{` and only two closing `}`.

Comment: Wow. I guess the answer is that I'm an idiot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While inputting a multi-line expression, sometimes you get lost or just don't care about completing it. .break will start over.

see also .help and http://nodejs.org/api/repl.html